How to use a logic level IRL510 as a swtich
I need to switch 3.7 Amps of load at 12 V with MOSFETs. Since I will use optocoupler between MCUs GPIO and base of the MOSFET, gate will receive 12V.
Using non-logic level MOSFETs such as IRF510 or 5N60C is not an option at 3.7 Amps. Even at 12V base will not open properly, so those overheat instantly without opening drain-source.  I am facing a problem with my IRL510 which behaves just like a non-logic MOSFET. It is not opening at all.
I have tested the circuit with IRL2203 and it works like a charm!!! Even with 5 V at the it opens Drain-Source fully without any noticeable heat dissipation. I was expecting IRL510 to behave the same.
My non-professional understanding is that MOSFETs usually with "L" in the marking are logic level, which should START opening at 5 V or below. This is found at "Gate-source threshold voltage" at datasheet. For IRL510 it is 1-2 V. And yet it is not switching at 12 V? Any tips where to find Vgs for max opening?
Am I missing anything? Or my IRL510s might be defective? (btw. tested all 10 with the same outcome). Probably 1 :) since I bought my IRL510s from a reputable store.


In what way will your load be connected to the pins? Or the supply for the load? Do they share a ground connection?

3.7 Ah and 400 mAh are not loads, but battery capacities. Please correct. Also, since your optocopler bridges grounds from one side to the other, they add noting but cost.

The IRL510 has 0.54 ohms of on resistance at Vgs = 5V. That is not really suitable as a power switch.
